# How to redirect vitors of old Facebook Fanpage to a new Fanpage

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-page

unfortunately we had to change the Username of our Facebook Fanpage from `bansdiving` to `germanbansdiving`.

Both Pages are still active but the older one should be deleted soon.

The point is, that we printed already 1000s of business cards with the old lionk on them.
Is there any way to redirect all visitors of the old page to the new page??

I tried several solutions with Fangates etc. but since we cannot define a default landing tab anymore, visitors of https://www.facebook.com/bansdiving will always land on the Timeline and not on the app page / redirecting page by default.